# Unable to scroll on following screens due to overlay of elements?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, scroll, automation, appium

[image]

JA
Unable to scroll on following screens due to overlay of elements?
Jatin · 2 days ago
Scenario- After filling all the details , user need to scroll from "for how many people" to bottom...

Line of code -

```
driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.TextView[@text='Send enquiry']").click();  

driver.findElementById("com.letsdogether.dogether:id/send_enquiry_dialog_send_button").click();

driver.findElementById("com.letsdogether.dogether:id/send_enquiry_date_text").click();

driver.findElementById("com.letsdogether.dogether:id/cancel").click();

driver.findElementById("com.letsdogether.dogether:id/send_enquiry_date_text").click();

// driver.findElementById("com.letsdogether.dogether:id/date_picker_year").click();

// driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.TextView[@content-desc=\"2020\"]").sendKeys("2020");

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.view.View[@index='24']")).sendKeys("25");

driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.Button[@text='OK']").click();

driver.findElementByAndroidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(true).instance(0)).scrollIntoView(new UiSelector().textContains(\"Message (Optional)\").instance(0))");
```

-------- scrolling is not happening by this command or neither from below command

```
// driver.findElementsByAndroidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable(new UiSelector()).scrollIntoView(text(\"Message (Optional)\"));");

driver.findElementById("com.letsdogether.dogether:id/send_enquiry_decrease_seats_button").click();

WebElement buttonElement = driver.findElement(By.id("com.letsdogether.dogether:id/send_enquiry_increase_seats_button"));

int i;

for(i=0;i<=10;i++) {

    buttonElement.click();

}

driver.findElementById("com.letsdogether.dogether:id/send_enquiry_dialog_send_button").click();

// driver.findElementById("com.letsdogether.dogether:id/send_enquiry_increase_seats_button").click();
```

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://www.automationtestinghub.com/appium-scroll-examples/) blog post does a good job of covering some of the ways you can scroll in Appium, specifically on Android. A few ways you can scroll to the bottom of your screen are:

- With UiScrollable, using scrollIntoView() and passing the identifier for the scrollable container. For example:

```
driver.findElement(MobileBy.AndroidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().resourceId(\"" + *scrollable container ID* + "\")).scrollIntoView("+ "new UiSelector().resourceId(\"" + *ID of the element you want to scroll to* + "\"))"));
```

- With UiScrollable, just execute a [scrollForward()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/uiautomator/UiScrollable.html#scrollForward()). For example,

```
driver.findElement(MobileBy.AndroidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().resourceId(\"" + *scrollable container ID* + "\")).scrollForward()"));
```

- Last resort, you can always use [TouchActions](https://appium.github.io/java-client/io/appium/java_client/TouchAction.html). For example,

```
TouchAction actions = new TouchAction(driver);
actions.press(startX,startY).waitAction(Duration.ofSeconds(1)).moveTo(endX, endY).release().perform();
```

You can determine the coordinates to begin and end your TouchAction either as a proportion of your screen size, or as specific coordinates from one element to another.

Google is your friend. Let me know if this helps!